# How to restrict users to only access their own media files in wordpress

Tags: attachments

```
<?php
$attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' =>'image') );
foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) {
        echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, 'medium' );
```

}
?>

hi i use this code to show media attachment in a custom template

how can i restrict users to only access their own media files from this code

Answer (score 0):

You can add an `author` parameter to array in `get_children`.

Line 2 of your code will look like this:

```
<?php
    $attachments = get_children( array('post_parent' => get_the_ID(), 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' =>'image', 'author' => get_current_user_id() ) );
```

Comment: and i want to naviggation from this code how?